# SQL Server - Query - How to get the last result of a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have to data tables. The first one with users:

[image: 1]

and the second with their orders.

[image: 2]

Is it possible to get the whole list of users with their respective last order ? Like this:

[image: 3]

This was my try, but isn't allowed:

```
select a.id  ,a.Name , b.Order ,b.Date
from users as a
left join (
  select  top 1 Orders.id  , Orders.order , Orders.Date  
  from Orders
  where Orders.id =  a.id
  order by orders.Date desc
  ) as b
  on a.ID = b.Id
```

Comment: Please read : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hello Marc and welcome to StackOverflow.  You'll find that images are not the recommended way to present data here that has a purely text content, especially when it is important for people to reproduce your results. **Linked** images are even more unwelcome than inline images.

Comment: @jarlh - `OUTER APPLY` in this case.

Comment: @MatBailie, you're correct! (I've never used SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use window functions:

```
select * 
from Users u 
left join ( 
   select * , row_number() over (partition by ID order by date desc) rn
   from orders 
) t on t.rn = 1 and u.id = t.id
```